# How to efficiently insert data to mysql using PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mariadb

I have some code where I am trying to take the `csv` file as input and use that `csv` data to insert into database.

I am using Maria DB. I have created a table using command line on terminal.

```
user_upload.php: 


<?php 
require "database.php";

$lines = file('users.csv', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES|FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', $lines);
$col_names = array_shift($csv);

$users = [];
foreach($csv as $row) {
    $users[] = [
        $col_names[0] => ucfirst(strtolower($row[0])),
        $col_names[1] => ucfirst(strtolower($row[1])),
        $col_names[2] => strtolower(strtolower($row[2])),
    ];
    try {
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO users(name, surname, email) 
            VALUES(:name, :surname, :email)");
            $stmt->bindParam(':name' $col_names[0]);
            $stmt->bindParam(':surname' $col_names[1]);
            $stmt->bindParam(':email' $col_names[2]);
            $stmt->execute();
    }catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
$dbh = null;

?>
```

database.php

```
<?php 

$hostname = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '*******';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=userDetails", $username, $password);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo 'Connected to Database<br/>';

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}


?>
```

My users table in sql:

[image]

In my code `user_upload.php` there is a foreach loop and I am inserting those values in database, but it does not seem right. I am new to it, so not sure the exact way of using PDO inside `foreach`. Also, I want to validate the email before inserting to mysql like 'useremail@gmail.com' so they should have @ in the email. How can I do that and also insert data to mysql in PDO properly? Any more information is needed if please let me know happy to provide.

Comment: `but it does not seem right` - can you pls be a bit more specific than this? Do you get an error or unexpected behaviour? Pls also ask 1 question per post, not multiple ones! There is an explicit close reason for posts with multiple questions!

Comment: @Shadow  By that I meant it connect to database over and over in the foreach loop so I don't think that's the right way to do

Comment: Who says it does connect over and over? As I can see this code connects only once in the database.php. And again, is there any *actual* problem with this code  that you can observe? Does it run slow, or gives an error?

Comment: @YourCommonSense No, I was just asking if it is right or not, or best way to do it. Yeah, sorry I thought it was connecting to sql over and over, my bad.

Comment: Okay, fair. Actually there is a better way. There *could* be a performance issue, depends on the certain database settings. And preparing the query in  a loop makes no sense - that's the actual idea of prepare that you are doing it once. and also adding try catch to echo the error makes no sense as well - PHP will echo the error without any additional code. But I just wanted to make a point that you must concentrate on finding the real problems in the code, not just "thinking" out of nowhere

Comment: @YourCommonSense Could you please tell me what's the efficient way to do then as in answer? So the performance is better.

Comment: Yes. I linked the answer at the top

Comment: @YourCommonSense I updated my answer. Could you please have a look if it is right or better now?

Comment: I can see it is for some reason not the same as in the linked answer. But as long as it works it's ok. when it starts to get slow you know what to do - add a transaction

Comment: also i don't understand why there are 2 loops, not one

Comment: @YourCommonSense I didn't understand how to write the same answer as first one (in the question you reckon) in my code, so I used another person code the below the first  answer in the other question

Comment: @YourCommonSense Did you mean I should add `$stmt->execute($user);` inside first `foreach` loop rather creating a new one below it?

Comment: I see absolutely no point in making another loop

Comment: I did that what you said but I have so many errors now no matter where I put the execute code

Comment: @YourCommonSense It would have been helpful if you could post an answer rather referring to other answers since I am new to it, so I am having hard time understanding what you're saying.

Comment: Sorry, but Stack Overflow is not a tutoring service. It's a Q&A service and apparently there is an existing answer to your question. In order to learn PHP in general, you have to attend some course or buy a book.